# How do I change the format of all dates in my dataframe from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd (in r)

Tags: r, dataframe, date

So I've got a data frame that looks something like this,

```
         Date        Age_group
1     01-06-2021        <17
2     01-06-2021       17-59
3     01-06-2021        >60 
4     02-06-2021        <17
5     02-06-2021       17-59
6     02-06-2021        >60
7     03-06-2021        <17
8     03-06-2021       17-59
9     03-06-2021        >60
```

and goes on a long way. And I need every date converted to yyyy-mm-dd. I've tried

```
as.Date("01/06/2021", format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

But obviously that just changed them all to that exact date in said format. Bare with me I'm very new to r, any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in 2 steps.  First, use `as.Date` to convert your text dates to bona fide R dates.  Then use `format` to convert back to text, in the format you want.

```
dates <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
df$Date <- format(dates, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `format`:

```
my_date <- as.Date("31-12-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y")

format(my_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2020-12-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Where "df" is the name of your dataframe.